# Fallout Shelter :: Does Mr. Handy Pick Up Loot?

Tags: fallout-shelter

I know that Mr. Handy will pick up caps when on walkabout; will he also pick up weapons and/or outfits?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Ok, let's see what Mr. Handy can do:

1. He can **collect resources** from the floor he's assigned to
2. He can be **used as helper** in case of room emergencies (fires, bugs, rat moles)
3. He can be used as defender when raiders or deathclaws attack. **Advantages are that he's tough, he doesn't count as a dweller so you can have now 7 defenders in one room, he'll travel to the room automatically** (if it's on his floor), so you don't have to assign him manually, like a dweller
4. He can **explore the Wasteland** but **can only collect caps** (but he's very good at collecting caps)
5. He **doesn't gain experience** (doesn't levels up)
6. He **cannot be healed** with stimpacks
7. He **can die**
8. He **can be revived** using caps exactly like a dweller (but costs around 2000 caps)
9. He **is vault specific**. Cannot be shared between your vaults.

That's pretty much it about Mr Handy.

**TL/DR: Mr. Handy cannot pick loot while exploring, only caps.**

Comment: Mr. Handy is really quite poor at picking up caps in the Wasteland, he just gets a few hundred per day.

Comment: Emphasis on the fact that he will only patrol a single floor. After getting a Mr. Handy as a quest reward and finding this out, I would have been super disappointed had I actually spent 99¢ to buy him.

Answer (score 2):

Mr handy will not collect loot, He only collects caps,  in my experience aswell he is quite slow about it and has not been damaged yet.

Answer (score 1):

It states in the pre game hints that Mr. Handy should pick up loot (items) while exploring the Waste, but so far I´ve never seen him do that.