# Can Mr. Handy's exploration outside the vault be upgraded?

Tags: fallout-shelter

It seems [Mr. Handy](https://imgur.com/a/Hz4oe) can be sent out into the wastelands to collect caps, but not equipment, with a few hilarious quips from him, but I'm wondering if you can upgrade Mr. Handy so that he collects more caps as he adventures outside?

[image]

I haven't found a Mr. Handy yet as he is a somewhat rare premium item from lunchboxes.

Comment: By the way, now Mr. Handy finds Caps even rarer. Back then he found Caps every 5 minutes, now he finds some every 20-22 Minutes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, Mr. Handy cannot be upgraded. He doesn't gain experience points and cannot be healed by stampacks.

About the loot, from experience, he will collect more and faster if you let him a few hours in the wasteland. He is very rare in lunchboxes but he can be bought for 1 euro (or around 4 euros for 5 Mr. Handy). It's not a bad price considering you can still revive Mr. Handy after he dies for 2000 caps. So you can keep him forever :)  (but cannot be changed between vaults)

You can learn more about Mr. Handy [**here**](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/232308/14953).

Comment: But then again, you can still revive any thing after they die, just for a hefty fee of credits. Is the same hefty fee there for Mr. Handys? Or is it a small static amount?

Comment: @howdareyou It's 2000 caps... I updated my answer

Answer (score 1):

**Yes, there is a way.** Simply wait, he'll find better and better stashes of Caps the more you leave him in the Wasteland.
*Example:in the first few hours / days, he will find a minimum of 1 or 2 Caps. In the next Days, you will see a minimum of 3, then 5, etc.*