# Does mister handy collect resources offline?

Tags: fallout-shelter

Or only when you're active/logged in to the game?
Also, do aim stimpacks and radaways count as "resources" that he collects?

Answer (score 5):

So a bit of an update since he has been out for a while. The help screen says he will collect resources while offline. What this actually appears to be is that when you load up you will get some initial extra resources from the floors that he is on.

Before I said he was also able to collect all resources (including Stimpaks and RadAWays) but will not actively level up players (which to me are the resources of the training rooms). He will however NOT accept a person from the radio rooms into the vault, that is also still something you have to do.

Answer (score 0):

Mr. Handy only collects resources when the game is running. He will collect from Power, Food, Water, Stimpak, and Radaway production rooms. He won't trigger a new dweller from the radio room, nor will he complete dwellers' level ups or stat training.

For more information, see [a summary of Mr. Handy's capabilities](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/232308/95791)