# What is the most optimal use for Mister Handy?

Tags: fallout-shelter

How can I use my Mister Handy in most optimal way?

Options that I see are:

- Send it to collect caps - This does not seems efficient enough for me. Not sure if its worth sending out.
- Just leave it to fight disasters/raiders.
- Let it auto collect resources. - I have all my resources separated in different floors.

Comment: Possibly relevant: [What Mr. Handy can do](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/232308/126370)

Comment: Also probably relevant: [It seems that Mr. Handy can pick up limited amount of resources offline](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/233611/126370).

Answer (score 4):

**I would create a new floor with different resources.**

You're right. Collecting caps isn't efficient, and defense is a simple job that is easily completed by dwellers, who, unlike Mr. Handy, can be armed with better weapons (like [Fat Man](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Fat_Man_(Fallout_Shelter))).

In my opinion, resource gathering is the most useful option.